# How to know the meaning/usage of 一

Tags: kanji, katakana

Well I'm a begginer, how do I know if **一** means ichi/itsu or its used for lengthening the word??

in **tenkaichi**(dragon ball) **ichiraku ramen**(naruto) the **一** is used there because it means best or one

I'm wondering if **一** can be used in spelling instead of **いち** even though the sentence doesn't mean one/best

and when i read some titles of eps, i don't know if the **一** means *1* or its used for *lengthening* the word

Answer (score 1):

When it appears in a kanji compound (or some compounds which mix kanji and kana), it is the kanji character for '[one](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E4%B8%80)' 一. This can be read as いち or ひと depending on the context. When it appears in kana words (mostly katakana), it is called a **chōonpu** ([超音符](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%C5%8Donpu)) and functions to lengthen the previous vowel.

> 日本一 (にほんいち) (kanji compound)
> ケーキ (keeki) (katakana)
> おーい (ooi) (hiragana)
> 万が一 (まんがいち) (mixed kanji and kana)